# HTML Form Submission to Existing Web Page

Tags: php, forms

I have an HTML form on a web page. Data from this form is received on a php page that stores this data in MySQL database.(<form action = URL of this page ....)

Code of that php page:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME','temp');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

// Create connection
$link=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

// Check connection
if (!$link)
{
    die('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db (DB_NAME, $link);

if(!$db_selected) {
    die(' Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ' : ' . mysql_error() );
}

$rollNo = $_POST['rollNo'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$item = $_POST['item'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tempstore(rollNo, password, name, item, place, description, contact) VALUES('$rollNo', '$password', '$name', '$item', '$place', '$description', '$contact') ";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die ('Error : ' . mysql_error() );
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

It works fine. But I want the same code on another existing php page. For that, when I add this code to an already existing php page and make it that form's action attribute's value, the problem is that when this php page is accessed directly it shows errors(undefined index :'rollNo','password'...). I think it is because it has not received any data from the form.

What changes should I make in this code to make it work in both cases:
1. When user directly opens the page.
2. When browser is redirected after submitting the form.

Comment: check all of your parameters with `isset` function

Comment: Have you set the `form` element's method to `post`? The default (if unspecified) is `get`.

Comment: yes I have. sorry I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Replace this php  code

```
if(isset($_POST['rollNo'])&& isset($_POST['password']) &&  isset($_POST['name'])&& isset($_POST['item'])){
$rollNo = $_POST['rollNo'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$item = $_POST['item'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tempstore(rollNo, password, name, item, place, description, contact) VALUES('$rollNo', '$password', '$name', '$item', '$place', '$description', '$contact') ";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die ('Error : ' . mysql_error() );
}
}
```

TO

```
$rollNo = $_POST['rollNo'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$item = $_POST['item'];
$place = $_POST['place'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO tempstore(rollNo, password, name, item, place, description, contact) VALUES('$rollNo', '$password', '$name', '$item', '$place', '$description', '$contact') ";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die ('Error : ' . mysql_error() );
}

mysql_close();
```

Comment: why you not tell me you what do you want in firstly

Comment: It works. I can directly see the web page very well. thanks. Although for some reason, still the form is submit to the old page I created (with only php code). I have changed the action attribute's value to this existing php page's url. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Sorry, now it's working perfectly. minor mistake. Thank you very much.